# CORS error in Node.js altough I'm using http and the same port

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm trying to send some data via jQuery AJAX request to my Node.js server. I start my app with `nodemon` and go to "localhost:3000/xxx". When I hit the button and try to send the data, Chrome tells me that "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." - but I'm using http, after all I'm on nodemon server. How can I solve this? On server side I'm using `cors` package (but I don't even think it's required since I'm requesting from the same port that the app is on).
Here's my AJAX request:

```
let ajaxOptions = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/search',
    data: request,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: updateResults,
    error: alert("Something went wrong")
}

    $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

Comment: Are you accessing `localhost:3000/search` from some other host like `localhost:3001`?

Comment: are you opening the browser with the physical local file by any chance? are you opening the browser with localhost:3000? If so, please include the serverside code along with ajax. Also, try running that code from the chrome devtools console. If it works, your javascript file is being served from local filesystem.

Comment: Assuming your page is at `localhost:3000`, have you tried to put '/search' only as the URL?

Comment: As I've written, I'm using `nodemon` for my server. I launch it, got to "localhost:3000/search" and there I have html page rendered by handlebars engine (maybe that's a problem). I send POST to "localhost:3000/search" and then get the CORS error. Maybe it's a problem with Handlebars, maybe the fact that I'm on the same route as the route I'm sending request for (but using POST), maybe Chrome somehow cached that JS (but I tried with Firefox, the same error). And yes, I've tried to put '/search', it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I somehow managed to solve the problem - I've checked all paths to my css and js files and it turns out that Handlebars had some troubles with them, after deleting them, restarting whole app couple and copying them in proper place it started to work - this and I also had to change url to '/search'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem you may be facing is that you are confusing `localhost` with `http`

But in reality these protocols are completely unique, an easy way to get around the CORS error is to simpily write `http` infront of localhost to force chrome to recognize it as an http request like such

```
http://localhost
```

you can read more about this on a chrome issue from 2010 [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743)